# Android studio "Failed To Instantiate one or more classes" error in design tab

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am currently learning Kotlin through a Udemy course for Android Development and I cannot proceed with the course unless I fix all the problems I'm having. One of these problems is "Failed To Instantiate one or more classes"
It gives a detailed description saying:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

- android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.  Exception Details java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener
```

I am new to Kotlin and Android Studio so there are a lot of things that I don't understand, I tried doing something in the Gradle but it just closed or crashed(I'm not really sure)Android Studio and I had to reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have this line in gradle (Module:app)  
`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'` or later  
then

```
Build/Clean Project

Build/Rebuild Project
```

and if necessary

```
File/Invalidate Caches / Restart
```